# URL to Keyword API

Tags: php, ajax, api, url, keyword

I'm trying to get keywords from any webpage I provide as a param.  Unfortunately meta-tag keyword data is no longer used and DIY text-parsing usually takes to long per request.  So I'm looking for one of the following two solutions:

**Solution 1: a URL to Keyword API**
Does anyone know of an API/service that allows you to send over the URL of a webpage and get keywords or refined categories back?

**or Solution 2: a quick text-parsing method**
Or is there any a quick (1s/request) easy text-parsing method on either the server-side (php) or client-side javascript that could return me a half-way decent set of keywords about any webpage I give it?

Comment: try this: http://www.webconfs.com/keyword-density-checker.php (not an API, but with curl and some phantazy you can work it out, i guess)

Comment: @c69, awesome!  seems light-weight even. but how do i get the code? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this artikel](http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2010/04/13/keyword-tool-api) sounds like [wordstream](http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2009/09/18/blog-review-roundup-free-keyword-tool) is what you're looking for. it has a [api](http://www.wordstream.com/keyword-tool-api) for (limited) free usage, too.